# Install packages through apt-get or gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, gem, aptitude

If a package is available both through apt-get and gem, which one should I choose?

I'm on Ubuntu and I don't know if I should install rake through apt-get or gem.

I use both apt-get and gem packages a lot.

What are the pros and cons with each?

Comment: Wrong forum to post this on, this is more of a superuser.com question... when it closes, it will be migrated across....

Comment: @tommieb75: I can see why this would fit in SU, but I'm kind of surprised that it's not seen as programming-related.

Comment: @Andrew: where does it say anything in the question in relation to programming....???!!! I do not see it... :) This is the right place for it and answers are below....! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always use RubyGems to install any kind of Gems (eg. Rails) to reduce confusion.

[Ruby on Rails: gem install versus apt-get](http://fak3r.com/2009/11/18/ruby-on-rails-gem-install-versus-apt-get/)

Comment: Using only `apt-get` would also reduce confusion. What about other reasons?

Answer (score 8):

You should use

#### apt-get

- If you care about uninstalling gems **with** their dependencies.
  RubyGems will not uninstall unused dependencies.
  See [do-i-have-to-manually-uninstall-all-dependent-gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952836/do-i-have-to-manually-uninstall-all-dependent-gems).
  If you care about uninstalling gems as a group, `rvm` is also an option (see below).
- If that gem would or should install executables in `/usr/bin`.
- If you want to upgrade gems together with the rest of the system (automatically)

#### gem

- If you want the most simple approach
- If you want to have multiple versions of a gem available on the system
- Need very recent or very old versions of some gems
- Want to install only for one user

#### [bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

- If you want to install certain gems only for one application

#### [rvm](https://rvm.io/) + gem

- If you need different sets of gems installed or removed independently

---

You should not mix between using `apt-get` and `gem` arbitrarily.
That means you should not, but when you do;
you should know and remember why you did this.

When you use different methods, the overall system gets more complex.

Comment: Please comment if some main reasons or consequences are missing. I still don't feel like I know the perfect solution myself.