# How install gem rails for all users in arch-linux

Tags: arch-linux, ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When install rails with

```
sudo gem install rails
```

or with root user, this install in `$HOME/.gem` and only works for actual user, how install for all users in the system ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to change your `/etc/gemrc` or `/root/.gemrc`.
The default is set to

```
gem: --user-install
```

Which does exactly what you observed.
You can use

```
gem install --no-user-install rails
```

See [Arch Wiki: Ruby](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ruby#RubyGems).

[install-packages-through-apt-get-or-gem](https://superuser.com/questions/178083/install-packages-through-apt-get-or-gem) is about the decision to use a package manager or `gem`.
Using `pacman` is the same as using `apt-get` in this case.

*EDIT:*

As mentioned by Hans:
Another option to use [pacgem](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacgem) to build an Arch Linux package from a gem on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pacgem which is available in AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacgem

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing files system-wide, always use your package manager for it.  Always, always, always.  ruby-rails is available in the AUR, and it will install as system-wide.  Read about [how to install packages from the AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR#Installing_packages) and perform the aforementioned with [this package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=37708).